# tcolorbox theorem which isn't framed on the sides

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

Minimal example:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{thm}{Theorem}
{theorem style=change apart,enhanced,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
titlerule=0.5em,toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=-0.1cm,top=0.2cm,
colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
title style={white!25!black},
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{Stokes}{stokes}
Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, 
and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
\[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

I would like to completely eliminate the frames on the side, while keeping the one on bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let me say, your settings are correct, but what you see are previewer artifacts. It depends on the previewer if you see the small lines or not.

I have two solutions how to get rid of these artifacts.

The first one changes your code just sligtly. Mainly, `enhanced` is replaced by `enhanced jigsaw`. The jigsaw variant uses another code to draw the frame which can be used for transparent boxes. Also, zero width lines are not displayed by many previewers:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{thm}{Theorem}{
  theorem style=change apart,
  enhanced jigsaw,% <--- jigsaw
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,
  left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
  titlerule=0.5em,
  toptitle=0.1cm,
  bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
  colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
  %title style={white!25!black},   & <---- remove
  fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{Stokes}{stokes}
Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$,
and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
\[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

This gives the expected result with Adobe Reader and SumatraPDF on Windows:

[image]

You may have a previewer which still shows left and right lines. In this case, I have a second solution. Here, I do not expect any artifacts because there is simply nothing drawn at all. The bottom rule is made by a `borderline south` option:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{thm}{Theorem}{
  theorem style=change apart,
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,interior hidden,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
  toptitle=0.1cm+1pt,%        <-- I used your values here
  bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,%  <-- I used your values here
  colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
  title style=white!25!black,
  bottomrule=1pt,%  <-- reserve space
  borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{white!25!black},%---- draw line
  fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{Stokes}{stokes}
Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$,
and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
\[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up having to use the second one, because preview still wouldn't cooperate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The individual rules can be set with `leftrule=0pt`, `rightrule=0pt`, etc. in the option argument of the `\newtcbtheorem` definition

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{thm}{Theorem}
{theorem style=change apart,enhanced,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,leftrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt, rightrule=0pt,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
titlerule=0.5em,toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=-0.1cm,top=0.2cm,
colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
title style={white!25!black},
fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{Stokes}{stokes}
Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, 
and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
\[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it still looks the same as my picture. Is there a way to add the horizontal line separately, i.e., so there is no frame?

Comment: @RandyRanderson: Do you have the latest `tcolorbox` release? I've used `3.50` (before texlive was freezed some weeks ago, but CTAN has 3.60 already). As far as I know, the `leftrule=0pt` must be specified after `boxrule=....`

Comment: I reinstalled MacTeX recently so I think so. I copied and pasted what you wrote but it looked the same, very thin vertical lines instead of none.

Comment: I test your answer, however on pdf picture seeing in Sumatra the left and right margins are still visible. If I look the MWE of OP in Adobe Reader, this borders disappear. So I suspect, that OP observe this lines since he doesn't use Reader ...

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, I am using the Adobe Reader. There are no lines. They are visible in `evince` however too.

Comment: OK, then the left and right margin is not necessary explicit set to zero? Anyway, it is good practice to do so.

Comment: Well unfortunately it shows up in Preview.

Comment: I guess I'll just use the hidden frames option and manually insert horizontal rules below the theorems. I'll accept the answer anyway, since this seems like a reasonable solution and I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: @RandyRanderson: Thanks for accepting. I'll try to figure out anyway. Perhaps I'll write a mail to the author of `tcolorbox`.